# HTML voice chat width Phonegap and node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cordova

Is it possible to make a live voice chat on a HTML app width Phonegap and node.js?

Alex,

Comment: Why not build a quick proto and check? Have a look at http://voicechatapi.com/#sec-3. Might eliminate the need for node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below cordova plugin for this functionality

https://github.com/luhuiguo/cordova-plugin-voice

Answer (score 1):

In a native app it would be possible to have voice chat, but that's because the code would be using the native APIs (a.k.a. programmed in Objective-C for iOS and Java for Android, with their respective SDKs). I have zero experience with PhoneGap, and I believe they're exposing some kind of API that lets you access the device's peripherals like the microphone or camera, so I'd be confident it's possible on the client side.

In a pure HTML website (not an app), it's achievable using Flash, and there has been some breakthroughs with WebRTC where users have been doing video conferences in a peer-to-peer setting. Peer-to-peer means they were connected to another, so that wouldn't work with your node.js setup.

Unfortunately the biggest hurdle, besides that WebRTC is not fully ready/implemented for HTML voice chat, is that if we're talking about a multi-user voice chat, you'll have to do a lot of 'muxing' (merging the audio signals together) and processing to make it work -- keeping in mind the user who just talked should not hear his own voice back. Servers who do this are known as multipoint control units (MCU). I'm pretty sure there's no MCU implementation for node.js unfortunately.